# Magento 2 - Layered navigation show products with salable quantity to 0

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, stock

In my store I have all products with only 1 quantity. When I buy a product, its "Salable Quantity" is 0 instead its "Quantity" stays 1 and thats ok, because the product is only "reserved" and the quantity decrease only after shipping. But in  Layered Navigation the product is show as available, but if I go in product detail page, the product is show as "Sold". Why in Layered Navigation the product is not show as "Sold"? Why in Layered Navigation Magento uses the Stock status and not the Salable Quantity to show if product is sold or not?